# ArcPy reclassify with if statement and cell value

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, spatial-analyst, reclassify

I have a workspace with NDVI rasters and another workspace with greyscale rasters. The rasters have the same name.

I want to reclassify the NDVI raster while also using the greyscale values in a function. Depending on the greyscale value, another reclass function should be used. So for every pixel, the correct function has to be found.

I need to use an if statement: if the greyscale raster cell value is high, another statement should be used but the code results in an error:

> Invalid use of raster with Boolean operator or function. Check the use of parentheses where applicable.

```
arcpy.env.workspace = ndviws
ndvirasterlist = arcpy.ListRasters()

for rimage in ndvirasterlist:
    ndvi_raster = arcpy.sa.Raster(rimage)
    grey_raster = arcpy.sa.Raster(os.path.join(greyvalues,rimage))
    if grey_raster <= 28523:
        output_raster = Con(ndvi_raster < -0.0000006 * grey_raster +  0.3448,2,1)
    if grey_raster >28523 and grey_raster < 50000:
        output_raster = Con(ndvi_raster < -0.000009 * grey_raster + 0.437673,2,1)
    if grey_raster >=50000:
        output_raster = Con(ndvi_raster < -0.000007 * grey_raster + 0.5233,2,1)
    output_raster.save(os.path.join(outputws,rimage))
```

**edit: **edited so that there are now 3 if statements. Is this still working with con method?**

Comment: You have "values" misspelled in arcpy.sa.Raster(os.path.join(greyvaluews,rimage)).  That could be a source of an error unless the variable name is similarly misspelled earlier in the program.

Comment: thank you PT. that was just a typing mistake since I couldnt copy paste the code here. Would you know how I can do that with 3 IF statements (not 2)?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't; my experience with rasters is a bit scattershot.  I know I've encountered errors because I've misspelled variables before, so I thought that might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if grey_raster <= 28523` does not make sense to arcpy. `28523` is the value you want to check against **each** pixel of `grey_raster`, which is where `Con` function comes handy.

In your case, you should use [nested conditions](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/conditional-evaluation-with-con.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_5B95B79898DA42AC8CBC1C1887BDD33E) like:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = ndviws
ndvirasterlist = arcpy.ListRasters()

for rimage in ndvirasterlist:
    ndvi_raster = arcpy.sa.Raster(rimage)
    grey_raster = arcpy.sa.Raster(os.path.join(greyvaluews,rimage))
    output_raster = Con(grey_raster <= 28523, Con(ndvi_raster < -0.0000006 * grey_raster +  0.3448,2,1), Con(ndvi_raster < -0.000009 * grey_raster + 0.437673,2,1))
    output_raster.save(os.path.join(outputws,rimage))
```

**EDIT**

If you have more than two conditions to check against, you can simply produce intermediate rasters, and work on them as you go (not tested):

```
arcpy.env.workspace = ndviws
ndvirasterlist = arcpy.ListRasters()

for rimage in ndvirasterlist:
    ndvi_raster = arcpy.sa.Raster(rimage)
    grey_raster = arcpy.sa.Raster(os.path.join(greyvaluews,rimage))
    # first condition (grey_raster <= 28523)
    output_raster = Con(grey_raster <= 28523, Con(ndvi_raster < -0.0000006 * grey_raster +  0.3448,2,1), 1)
    # second condition (grey_raster >28523 and grey_raster < 50000)
    output_raster = Con((grey_raster > 28523) & (grey_raster < 50000), Con(ndvi_raster < -0.000009 * grey_raster + 0.437673,2,1), output_raster)
    # third condition (grey_raster >=50000)
    output_raster = Con(grey_raster >= 50000, Con(ndvi_raster < -0.000007 * grey_raster + 0.5233,2,1), output_raster)
    output_raster.save(os.path.join(outputws,rimage))
```

Comment: thank you @umbe1987.
In my real case I have 3 if statements, not just 2 (above was just an example). I guess I can't use the con method then? Which alternative would you suggest?

Comment: Not sure if it will work, but I provided another possible solution. Feel free to test it and report back your results if you want.

Comment: your edit worked when i changed "output_raster>28523" to "grey_raster>28523" in the second and "output_raster >=50000" to "grey_raster >=50000" in the third condition. Also at the very end of condition 2 and 3 I had to change the value 1 to the variable "output_raster", since the values were overwritten before. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad it helped. I changed the code according to your comments so that it will be correct.